# Is there a connection between the declination of a last meal and whether or not a person’s guilt has been posthumously disputed and challenged?

Tags: law-enforcement, prisoner

The documentary *Last Supper* ([IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2000418/) / [full video on Vimeo](http://vimeo.com/10964671)) by Mats Bigert, and Lars Bergstrom released in 2005 suggests that there is a connection between the declination of a last meal and whether or not a person’s guilt has been posthumously disputed and challenged. Are there evidence backing up this claim?

I am aware of Kniffin, Kevin M., and Brian Wansink. "[Death Row Confessions and the Last Meal Test of Innocence](http://www.mdpi.com/2075-471X/3/1/1)." Laws 3.1 (2013): 1-11, but they focus on self-perceived innocence.

Comment: So you want to differentiate between self-perceived innocence and innocence percieved by others ("guilt has been ... disputed and challenged")? Even if there are strong indications of several wrongful executions, I believe that at least in the US, no execution has actually been proven wrongful by a court of law?

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wrongful_execution#United_States: "Chipita Rodriguez was hanged in San Patricio County, Texas in 1863 for murdering a horse trader, and 122 years later, the Texas Legislature passed a resolution exonerating her."

Comment: @Franck: That article contradicts the article about Chipita Rodriguez herself where Wikipedia writes: "the Texas Legislature passed a resolution noting that Rodriguez did not receive a fair trial". Other web articles present both variations, that she was either exonerated or that it was declared that she did not receive a fair trial. I am not able to find the actual resolution online, so I can't tell which is true. Nevertheless, one case is hardly enough to build a statistic on.